# Objective-C memory management and nil?

Tags: objective-c, memory

In my book a `*joystick` that was assigned `@property (nonatomic, retain)`, and it wasn't released only set to `nil` in the `-dealloc` method. In the `-init` method, the same joystick was set to `nil`. What does this mean?

Comment: If it's not released in the dealloc, that's a memory leak if it's allocated or retained in the init. For example: myproperty = [aProperty retain] or self.myproperty = aProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain)
```

the setter method generated by `synthesize` will take care of releasing the object currently pointed to by the ivar before assigning the new one to it. So,

```
self.property = xxx;
```

is equivalent (if you like) to:

```
if (property != xxx) {
    [xxx retain];
    [property release];
    property = xxx;
}
```

Now, it is considered good practice to set an ivar to nil after releasing it:

```
[property release];
property = nil;
```

This is a common release idiom in ObjC.

As you see, if you assign nil to a property (i.e., xxx = nil in the example above) what you get is just this: the ivar will be released and its value set to nil. Assigning nil to a property is therefore just a shorthand for this "release idiom".

Comment: +1, but correct `property = xxx;` — it should be `property = [xxx retain];`

Comment: @Anton: you are right, thanks! I was writing by memory thinking about the release part...

Comment: thanks for the reply! Does that mean if something like `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name` only has to be set to nil in the dealloc method? And that releasing it in the dealloc method is optional?

Comment: You can set a property to nil whenever it makes sense (consider a label, when it is non-nil you display it, when it is nil you don't). And you should alway release, one way or another, in `dealloc` if you care about memory leaks. Don't count on being able to foresee what happens to your ivars, so that you can skip this... furthermore, properties make it so simple...

Comment: I'd say `self.property = xxx'` is equivalent to `if (property != xxx) { [property release]; property = [xxx retain]; }`, i.e. the retain should also only happen if xxx does not equal the value already there. IIRC, this is surrounded by locks too, but I may be remembering incorrectly.

Comment: @sergio: your correction is better than what I wrote. Mine could dealloc it before it could be retained. +1

Comment: um so how would you release `name`? With a `[name release]` and `name = nil` in the dealloc method or just a `name = nil` in the dealloc method?

Comment: The standard way is: `[name release]; name = nil;`. you can use `self.name = nil;` as a shorthand to the same effect (but then you should be sure that the property is a `retain` one). Actually, using the property is not as clear and could be considered bad practice, because you say you do something (assigning nil), but you are looking for a side effect of doing that (releasing and assigning nil).

Comment: Oh I'll just use the standard way instead of the short cut then. :p But why was joystick only set to nil and never released? Won't that cause a memory leak? Why was it set to nil in the init method? Thanks again!

Comment: please, notice that `self.name = nil` is different to `name = nil`; the latter will not release, thus it would be a memory leak. setting to nil in the init method means simply setting an initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are essentially automaticaly generated accessor method to you ivars, you can even override properties, so if you property is call joystick then the automatically generate method is equallent to

```
- (void)setJoystick:(MyType *)aValue
{
    if( aValue != joystick )
    {
        [joystick release];
        joystick = [aValue retain];
    }
}
```

more than this actually happens if you do not have nonatomic, and there maybe stuff to deal with thread access.

Sp you can see that if you set self.joystick you are calling setJoystick: with nil and so release the current value and setting the ivar to nil

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is joystick being retained or is it aValue? In `joystick = [aValue retain];`

Comment: Yes to both, aValue and joystick are pointer to some location in memory. Think of pointers as indices to memory blocks, initial joystick has the value 6 which refers to memory block 6, aValue has the value 8 which point to memory block 8, [joystick release], tell the memory at block 6 to decrease its reference count, [aValue retain] just increase the retain count of memory block 8 and then returns 8, so that joystick now is assign 8, referring to the exact same memory block.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what's going on in the @synthesize now.